# socket.io app hangs in production environment

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, socket.io

I am using socket.io based chat application.

I have established an eventing mechanism between client and server. It works fine in the development.

But when i deploy the same code to production and multiple users start using it. After some time of use the application hangs. Node.js server stops responding.
I found that when the user is disconnected he can not connect back again.

My server side code

```
    app.listen(3006);
console.log('listening on port 3006');

//socket io event listening
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
```

Below is the client code

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> 
  <script>
    var socket =io();
```

i am on socket io 1.4.5 and using express with node.js

I think the tcp connections opened by web sockets are opened, reaches the max limit and any new connection is refused.
does client have to perform any thing on the disconnect socket.io event to release the tcp conncetion ?

Best Regards,
Saurav

Comment: WHere is your production hosted ? are you sure you are not limited in parallel websocket connections ?

Comment: its hosted on a linux machine...i am not sure about parallel web socket connections...how do i check it ?... this is the only application being hosted in my machine which uses web sockets

Comment: is it hosted on a cloud Platform ? locally ? :)

Comment: not a cloud platform...just a machine on network which is running node.js server

Comment: can you share your socket.io client codE?

Comment: updated with the client socket.io initialization code , then the socket object is used to emit the messages

Comment: Hm it is not easy to understand why here... I think the best thing to do is to create a light sample without your production code into it and published it here so we can reproduce the issue on our side